# How to add other model fields in rails_admin for load document in activestorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, rails-admin

I'm just starting to learn gem 'rails_admin' and don't understand much yet.

I have two models connected by a polymorphic relationship

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :object_documents
end
```

and

```
class ObjectDocument < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :object, polymorphic: true

  has_many_attached :document
end
```

in event model i want to add name field for loaded document
and the document itself (naturally, all this data will be taken from the ObjectDocument model)

I've been scratching my head for a long time and don't know how to implement it.

Maybe I'm going in the wrong direction. Sorry for my English, it's not my native language

i tried to do it this way

```
module RailsAdminModels
  module Event
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      rails_admin do
       edit do
        field :object_documents do
          partial "object_document"
        end
      ...
```

but it doesn't work for me. Or I don't style the view correctly